# Tikz newcommand error with \draw

Tags: tikz-pgf, macros

I have the following `newcommand` in my preamble, to create smaller network diagrams as inline text:

```
\usepackage{tikz}
\def\unit{0.05}
\def\uppernode{(.25,.33)}
\def\lowerrightnode{(.5,0)}
\newcommand{\opentri}{%
\begin{tikzpicture}%
  \draw[fill=black] (0,0) circle (\unit) \uppernode circle (\unit) \lowerrightnode circle (\unit);%
  \draw (0,0) -- \uppernode -- \lowerrightnode;%
\end{tikzpicture}}
\newcommand{\closedtri}{%
\begin{tikzpicture}%
  \draw [fill=black] (0,0) circle (\unit) \uppernode circle (\unit) \lowerrightnode circle (\unit);%
  \draw (0,0) -- \uppernode -- \lowerrightnode -- (0,0);%
\end{tikzpicture}}
```

However, when I use `\closedtri` and/or `\opentri` (in Overleaf), I have an `undefined control sequence` error in the line and the following error output in the log:

```
\closedtri ->\begin {tikzpicture}\draw 
                                       [fill=black] (0,0) circle (\unit ) \u...
l.326 ... metrics for closed triangle \closedtri.}
                                                  \vspace{1cm}
The control sequence at the end of the top line
of your error message was never \def'ed. If you have
misspelled it (e.g., `\hobx'), type `I' and the correct
spelling (e.g., `I\hbox'). Otherwise just continue,
and I'll forget about whatever was undefined.

! Undefined control sequence.
\closedtri ...owerrightnode circle (\unit );\draw 
                                                  (0,0) -- \uppernode -- \lo...
l.326 ... metrics for closed triangle \closedtri.}
                                                  \vspace{1cm}
The control sequence at the end of the top line
of your error message was never \def'ed. If you have
misspelled it (e.g., `\hobx'), type `I' and the correct
spelling (e.g., `I\hbox'). Otherwise just continue,
and I'll forget about whatever was undefined.
```

Any ideas what is causing it?

Here's the full file (without text parts that contain no errors). The error arises in the caption of the figures:

```
\documentclass{article}

% Replace `english' with e.g. `spanish' to change the document language
\usepackage[english]{babel}
% Set page size and margins
% Replace `letterpaper' with `a4paper' for UK/EU standard size
\usepackage[%
    letterpaper,%
    top=2cm,%
    bottom=2cm,%
    left=3cm,%
    right=3cm,%
    marginparwidth=1.75cm%
]{geometry}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage[colorlinks=true, allcolors=blue]{hyperref}
\usepackage{authblk}

\usepackage{tikz}
\def\unit{0.05}
\def\uppernode{(.25,.33)}
\def\lowerrightnode{(.5,0)}
\newcommand{\opentri}{%
\begin{tikzpicture}%
  \draw[fill=black] (0,0) circle (\unit) \uppernode circle (\unit) \lowerrightnode circle (\unit);%
  \draw (0,0) -- \uppernode -- \lowerrightnode;%
\end{tikzpicture}}
\newcommand{\closedtri}{%
\begin{tikzpicture}%
  \draw [fill=black] (0,0) circle (\unit) \uppernode circle (\unit) \lowerrightnode circle (\unit);%
  \draw (0,0) -- \uppernode -- \lowerrightnode -- (0,0);%
\end{tikzpicture}}


\title{Title}
\author[1]{Pablo Lozano}
\date{}

\begin{document}
\maketitle

\section{Figures}

In Figures~\ref{fig:three-baseline-diffInit-diffLr-complete} and \ref{fig:three-baseline-diffInit-diffLr-path} we observe that...
\begin{figure}[htbp]
\centering
\includegraphics[width=1.\textwidth]{figures/three/base/data_base_replace_diffInit_diffLr_usingRandom_usingGoodDistr_complete/metrics_evo_60_avg.png}
\caption{\label{fig:three-baseline-diffInit-diffLr-complete}Baseline model metrics for closed triangle \closedtri.}\vspace{1cm}
\includegraphics[width=1.\textwidth]{figures/three/base/data_base_replace_diffInit_diffLr_usingRandom_usingGoodDistr_path/metrics_evo_60_avg.png}
\caption{\label{fig:three-baseline-diffInit-diffLr-path}Baseline model metrics for open triangle \opentri.}
\end{figure}
```

Comment: I have no issues when use your code. What else you have in your document?

Comment: Please, be so kind and extend your code fragment to complete small document. Now we can only guess, what you have (not) in preamble ...

Comment: Expanded it. Thanks

Comment: Try `\protect\closedtri` and `\protect\opentri`.

Comment: @user187803 have the right answer. Also, `\label{}` don't need be in the `\caption` command